# How to insert UIImage to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios

I've got a problem with UIImage in the tableviewcell that are in storyboard.
When i scroll cell in the tableview it request the data from the server everytime so cell is very slow.
I've watched this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7butieUoBg)
but it does not work on storyboard, because storyboard donesn't have UITableViewCell NIB file (its integrate to the storyboard)

**What I do in my project**

1. I create object and link to my outlet property
2. I use json to get data from internet.
3. I display it on the tableview.

You can download my entire project file [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?ra8mmw89dj4ybaa). This is code in the UITableview.m `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSDictionary *entry = [ _entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.boomTitle.text = [entry objectForKey:@"body"];
    NSString *imageURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://kelnakub.co.cc/upload/%i.jpg",[[entry objectForKey:@"IdEntry"] intValue]];
    for(NSDictionary *dic in _entries)
    {
        NewsFeed *myNewsFeed = [[NewsFeed alloc]init];
        myNewsFeed.thumNail = [dic objectForKey:@"IdEntry"];
    }

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURL];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    cell.boomImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    cell.boomDate.text = [entry objectForKey:@"dateCreated"];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITableViewCell in a NIB file using storyboard. Just use prototype cells and, instead of designing the cell on the Storyboard, create a new NIB and design the UITableViewCell on it (Storyboard's UITableView remains empty of cells).

Then, in the code, you can load the cell using something like: `UITableViewCell * MyCustomCell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:1];`